# How do I use Storybook in React Native with my main project?

Tags: android, react-native, storybook

I have a React Native project setup using `react-native init` and am using Storybook to develop my components in isolation. I ran the `getstorybook` command inside this project and the CLI generated a `storybook` directory with all the necessary files, as described in the [Storybook docs](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/tree/master/app/react-native).
When I run `npm run storybook` command followed by `react-native run-android`, I'm able to view the stories on my emulator. Now if I need to run my main app (not storybook, but the one which was generated by the `react-native init` command), I have to run `npm run start` followed by `react-native run-android`.
Is there a way to not have to build the app every time I switch from Storybook to my main app? Am I missing something obvious here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For now, I'm using two separate emulators, one for Storybook and the other for the main app